# Restrict backend but allow to use post.php?action=delete&post=POSTID from front-end

Tags: plugins, user-roles, front-end, content-restriction

Restrict backend.

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && !( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

This code will restrict backend for all users roles except for admin which is what I want. However, I want to allow Authors to delete their posts from front-end using `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&post=63&_wpnonce=c67eff49b7` link on Delete button.

Is it possible to exclude that link for the redirect? So authors can delete their posts from front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to access `post.php` and still restrict the back-end. You need have action, action name as `delete`, post key and value, and wpnonce kay and value. Otherwise, it will redirect you to homepage.

```
function disable_wp_admin() {

    if ( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return;

    if (( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) )
        return;

    if ( 'post.php' == isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'delete' == $_REQUEST['action'] && isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] ) )
        return;

    $redirect_to = home_url();
    wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_wp_admin' );
```